# how to solve these compile errors when compiling GHC source code

Tags: compiler-errors, ghc, freebsd

I tried to compile GHC master source code on a machine running FreeBSD 10.3 and got some compile errors. What I did following the steps:

```
1. $ git clone --recursive git://git.haskell.org/ghc.git
2. $ ./boot
3. $ ./configure --prefix=$HOME
4. $ gmake -j2
```

And the compile errors:

```
Common.hsc: In function 'main':
Common.hsc:225:16: error: 'OFDEL' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:225:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:226:16: error: 'OFILL' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:227:16: error: 'NL0' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:228:16: error: 'NL1' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:229:16: error: 'CR0' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:230:16: error: 'CR1' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:231:16: error: 'CR2' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:232:16: error: 'CR3' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:234:16: error: 'TAB1' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:235:16: error: 'TAB2' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:237:16: error: 'BS0' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:238:16: error: 'BS1' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:239:16: error: 'VT0' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:240:16: error: 'VT1' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:241:16: error: 'FF0' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
          ^
Common.hsc:242:16: error: 'FF1' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/test/ghc/inplace/lib/template-hsc.h:38:10: note: in definition of macro 'hsc_const'
     if ((x) < 0)                                      \
```

---

I firstly used gcc as my `CC` environment value, then switched to `clang` but also failed. I have all the prerequisites like ghc8.0, alex, happy etc installed and have installed latest gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systems like this that are oriented on rapid development and research often require a lot of very careful reading and work to set up.

E.g. did you follow the instructions for setting up your system [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Preparation/FreeBSD)?  These instructions imply your `configure` and `gmake` commands were lacking.

The error messages are saying constants normally defined in the header `termios.h` of the standard terminal control package aren't there. There are many possible causes. But the `configure` and also `gmake` commands are prime suspects.

Also note the page is saying `gcc 4.6` is new. That means it hasn't been updated in quite a while. You may have your work cut out for you.